# Editing Width of Weebly Landing Page Image

Tags: css, weebly

My weebly landing page has a section at the top with half of it as text and the other half as an image.  The problem is that there is always a gap to the right of the image and whatever is to its right.  For example, if the image is "float: right" there will be a gap between the image and the border (banner?).  If I flip flop the image and text and do "float: left" for the image there will be a gap between the image and the text box.  I've tried changing the widths of just about everything, as well as the paddings of the image and text.

Attached is an image with the picture on the left. You will see the gap between the image and text.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  apparently I can't post images yet.

```
  #bannerleft {
        float: right;
        width: 466px;
        height: 288px;
        padding: 0px 15px;
        background: url(banner-left.png);
        border: 0px #222 solid;
        border-right: none;
    }

    #bannerleft h2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    #bannerleft p {
        padding: 8px 0px;
        line-height: 130%;
    }

    #bannerleft .wsite-button {
        margin: 3px;
    }

    #banner-right {
        float: left;
        width: 490px;
        height: 268px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual website? I would guess that the gap is related to some whitespace that is part of the HTML.

Comment: I haven't published the website yet.  I'd love to be able to post a screen shot of it :\

Comment: I'll look at the HTML for the landing page, although HTML is even more confusing to me than CSS.

Comment: Post the HTML of the relevant section, a screenshot isn't actually necessary.

Comment: Oh boy, edit your answer and include it there in a proper code block and delete your comments.

Comment: so ugly.  Sorry :\  I'm new to this.

Comment: Check out the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Looks good, but it contains too much code, you should only post the relevant portion of the document which is affected by the issue you are facing. Also post the actual HTML which you see in your browser (Ctrl + u) and not the template from your Weebly software.

Comment: OH OK.  I posted the relevant section of the CSS.